# Bing search API can't get any result for arabic

Tags: bing

string query = "123";

```
        // Create a Bing container.
        string rootUrl = "https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search";
        var bingContainer = new Bing.BingSearchContainer(new Uri(rootUrl));

        // The market to use.
        string market = "ar-XA";

        // Get news for science and technology.
        string newsCat = "rt_ScienceAndTechnology";
```

bingContainer.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("...", "...");

// Build the query, limiting to 10 results.
            var newsQuery =
                bingContainer.News(query, null, market, null, null, null, null, newsCat, null);
            newsQuery = newsQuery.AddQueryOption("$top", 10);

```
         //Run the query and display the results.
        var newsResults = newsQuery.Execute();

        foreach (var result in newsResults)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}-{1}\n\t{2}",
             result.Source, result.Title, result.Description);
        }
```

Why can this work for other language like japan, only can't work for arabic！Does bing search API haven't did any test in arabic?

Answer (score 0):

Bing can return results for Arabic.  The particular query term you provided just happened to not be in the Bing index for Arabic results.  Should you have searched for a term in the index like "mosque", results would have been returned.  See the query below

https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/v1/Web?Query=%27mosque%27&Market=%27ar-XA%27

Bingfoot